# Evaluating dynamically generated statements in Python

Tags: python, eval

I need to dynamically generate python code and execute it with eval() function.

What I would like to do is to generate some "imports" and "assign values". I mean, I need to generate this string to evaluate it `eval(x)`.

```
x = """
import testContextSummary
import util.testGroupUtils
testDb = [testContextSummary.TestContextSummary, 
          testGroupUtils.testGroupUtils.TestGroupUtils]
""" # x is automatically generated
eval(x)
... use testDb ...
```

I tried with this code, but eval() returns an error not recognizing `import`, so I tried this code.

```
x = """
testContextSummary = __import__("testContextSummary")
testGroupUtils = __import__("util.testGroupUtils")
testDb = [testContextSummary.TestContextSummary, 
          testGroupUtils.testGroupUtils.TestGroupUtils]
""" # x is automatically generated

eval(x) # error
```

I again got an error not allowing assignment statement.

Is there any way to execute dynamically generated python script, and use the result from the evalution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `exec` instead of `eval`.

```
>>> s = "x = 2"
>>> exec s
>>> x
2
```

Of course, please don't use `exec` on untrusted strings ...

Comment: prosseek: It's because `exec()` can handle multiple lines of Python, whereas `eval()` only evaluates a single expression. Be safe.

Comment: @martineau: I didn't see the original comment, but the same caveats with `exec` apply equally to `eval` and it has nothing to do with multiple lines of code ... (`__import__('os').remove('important_file')`)

Answer (score 0):

This may also work:

```
x = """[
        __import__("testContextSummary").TestContextSummary, 
        __import__("util.testGroupUtils").testGroupUtils.TestGroupUtils]
"""
testDB=eval(x)
```

Comment: While that might work in this particular case, things could get tricky if there were multiple names defined or there was more complicated logic in the dynamically generated code, like `if/else` constructs and/or function/class definitions, etc -- all of which `exec()` ought to be able to handle.