# Is it possible to run python variable declarations from a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

This is the behaviour I'm looking for...

```
"a = 2" # execute this line
print a
> 2
```

I know about the `exec` statement but I need it to work in python 2 and 3 and python 3 does not allow exec to create local variables. Is there another way around this?

EDIT: Like I said - I know that I can't use `exec`, the accepted answer of the supposed duplicate is saying to use `exec`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating dynamically generated statements in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951937/evaluating-dynamically-generated-statements-in-python)

Comment: I would not suggest `exec` or `eval`, but can do `locals()['a'] = 2` (not saying its good, but definitely safer)

Comment: @RafaelC: [Modifying the dict returned by `locals()` is unsupported too.](https://ideone.com/MlKtZJ)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign the value of a variable using eval in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599283/how-can-i-assign-the-value-of-a-variable-using-eval-in-python)

Comment: @user2357112 works in terminal/Ipython ?

Comment: @RafaelC: It fails inside a function, the same case where `exec` fails.

Comment: @user2357112 can do `globals()['a']=2` , not sure recommended

Comment: can you just share the snippet for a min in the comment and delete it

Comment: @RafaelC And that creates a global variable, not a local variable, which the OP has expressed a need to do.

Comment: @chepner don't know about that, accepted answer used globals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont necessarilly think this is a good idea ...

```
import ast
def parse_assignment(s):
    lhs,rhs = s.split("=",1)
    globals()[lhs] = ast.literal_eval(rhs)

parse_assignment("hello=5")
print(hello)
parse_assignment("hello2='words'")
print(hello2)
parse_assignment("hello3=[1,'hello']")
print(hello3)
```

https://repl.it/repls/BiodegradableLiveProgrammer

Comment: I'm just writing a simple script - not an enterprise level python project so this is working fine. I'm curious, what are the ramifications if this kind of code existed in a huge python project that many people were using?

Comment: its just a weird way of setting variables that becomes hard to debug when things dont go right basically ... theres not much security ramifications, mosty it can become hard to track down problems