# update a pandas dataset, using pandas.eval or df.apply

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with  a lot rows.
One of the columns, lets say `WHERE_CLAUSE` has some sql like conditions. So I created a new column which uses these conditions and translates it to python/pandas statements.
Eg:  column `'WHERE_CLAUSE'` has the value for a row like `'ACCOUNTING_PERIOD NOT IN (999)'`  , I am translating it to a pandas statement in a new column `'EVAL_EXPR'` with value `'''base_table.loc[(base_table.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.isin([999]),"REPORT_TYPE_ID")] = "initial"'''`. 
 Now this is a perfectly valid statement if I execute it directly and it does update the dataset.

The problem  I face is, since it's a string,  I am using
`pandas.eval` which has the above value and it fails

So this is what I tried:

```
eval_str ='''base_table.loc[(base_table.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.isin([999]),"REPORT_TYPE_ID")] = "initial"'''
print(eval_str)
pd.eval(eval_str)
```

and this is the **error**  I receive:

```
>  base_table["REPORT_TYPE_ID"].apply(lambda x: "final" if  
> base_table.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.isin([999]))
> 
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-   
> packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code  
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
> 
>   File "<ipython-input-31-96405158714d>", line 9, in <module>  
> pd.eval(eval_str)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\eval.py",
> line 332, in eval
>     parsed_expr = Expr(expr, engine=engine, parser=parser, env=env)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py",
> line 764, in __init__
>     self.terms = self.parse()
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py",
> line 781, in parse
>     return self._visitor.visit(self.expr)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py",
> line 375, in visit
>     return visitor(node, **kwargs)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py",
> line 381, in visit_Module
>     return self.visit(expr, **kwargs)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py",
> line 375, in visit
>     return visitor(node, **kwargs)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py",
> line 583, in visit_Assign
>     raise SyntaxError("left hand side of an assignment must be a single name")
> 
>   File "<string>", line unknown SyntaxError: left hand side of an
> assignment must be a single name
```

I know pandas.apply doesn't take statements but expressions which is obviously what I am trying to execute. But how do I fix this?
I dont know how to tweak this ,so that I can use `dataframe['column'].apply` to avoid this issue. 
Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So to execute a dynamically generated python statement, I used this function 'exec'.It worked like charm!

**Code Tried**:

```
eval_str = '''base_table.loc[(base_table.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.isin([999]),"REPORT_TYPE_ID")] = "initial"'''
exec(eval_Str)
```

**Reference**:

It was already answered in stackoverflow.  [Evaluating dynamically generated statements in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951937/evaluating-dynamically-generated-statements-in-python)